Accessing X11 window pixel data over shared memory
I am writing a program in which I need to access a X11 window's pixel data as efficiently as possible, ideally over shared memory, without needing to make XCB calls every time I want to refresh the pixel data. It's a similar idea as Xvfb's -shmem option, but I want to access per-window pixel data over shared memory, rather than the entire screen.
I can configure the X server in whatever way helps with this. The X server is running headless and not connected to real video hardware.
I am aware of the XShm and XComposite extensions. From what I can see, they each do only one half of what I need:

The XComposite extension moves the window pixel data to an offscreen buffer that holds the pixel data.
The XShm extension allows creating shared memory regions and pixmaps that can be updated from existing windows (but only on demand, and requiring memory copying, as far as I can tell).

Can I somehow combine these two extensions such that I can directly access the window pixel data from my own application, without needing to continuously ask the X server to copy pixel data?

No you cannot cause pixel data to be allocated in your own memory. You need a display card to show a picture, and a display card has its own memory. Only data in that memory can be directly shown. (Some cards can use main RAM as displau memorym but not all).

Perhaps what you need is XRender? It's as fast as it gets.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I understand why it is this way for "regular" X servers connected to real hardware, but in my case it's running headless without video hardware (edited question to make that clear). Thanks for the reference to XRender though, it does look like the closest answer to what I'm looking for in the real-hardware case.

X11 doesn't have special treatment for this case. It would be a nightmare to implement it. Window buffer memory is not contiguous within the framebuffer to begin with. On top of that, a window may be partially obscured and/or covered with a semi-transparent window so you cannot really update the buffer yourself. What is your X problem?

My goal is to create a way to transparently run untrusted GUI applications on a Linux host without a VM. To that end, I am writing a sandboxing application that runs an X server inside a userspace kernel (gVisor), and I want to display the contents of the windows running on the sandboxed X server as regular windows on the host's X server.
So I am creating windows on the host X server, and their pixel data should exactly mirror the pixel data contained within the sandboxed X server's memory. I am investigating how to do this with as little memory copying as possible.

I've come up with something using Xvfb's -fbdir argument which causes Xvfb to store per-screen pixel data as memory-mappable files. If I put each window on its own screen and size the screens to match the sizes of the windows, in theory I should be able to access the window pixel data through that, though I haven't verified that this works beyond one screen yet.
Another path might be something like what Qubes does using a fake video driver and run the X server with an LD_PRELOAD library that hooks X's glibc calls to share the pixel data pages.

Per comments, this is not really possible because the X server's memory model assumes that X11 window pixel data lives in video hardware memory, thus the concept of "shared memory" with regular processes doesn't necessarily make sense in this context. In my context, however, the X server is not running on real video hardware.
The best solution I've found so far for my use-case is to use a multi-headed Xvfb instance with the -fbdir flag set to a directory within /dev/shm, then ensuring that each window is on its own screen that is sized to the window's size. Then, each screen maps to a window one-to-one, and each of them has a memory-mappable file under the directory pointed to by -fbdir.
